# JAVA: Parsing OPEN API with swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPI

Tags: java, spring, maven, swagger, swagger-3.0

I'm trying to parse an OPEN API URL this is the following code for it

```
OpenAPI openAPI = new OpenAPIV3Parser().read("https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json");
```

which is giving me the following exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactoryBuilder
```

The library which i'm using is

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-parser-v3</artifactId>
<version>2.0.19</version>
```

Is there any other library which i can use for parsing OPEN API 3.0?

Comment: Seems like you have multiple jackson core libraries. Can you exclude one. You can check that by firing mvn:dependency:tree

Answer (score 2):

If you check OpenAPI.read() it accepts either

1. (String location) or
2. (String location, List auths, ParseOptions resolve)

But what you are trying with is "String **URL**", instead try giving (String "**filePath**") with below dependency. It will work like charm.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.26</version>
</dependency>
```

Note:

```
 OpenAPI openAPI = new OpenAPIV3Parser().read(filePath) for OpenAPI3.0
 Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser().read(filePath)   for Swagger2.0
```

Check out below read() snippet handy for your clarity.

[image]

You can use swagger editor to switch json file type to yaml.
Swagger editor >> Edit >> Convert to YAML >> downloaded file move it to **filePath**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.25</version>
</dependency>
```

This works for me parsing OpenAPI and Swagger Specifications